# PipedOutputStream write speed on android 7

Tags: android, inputstream, outputstream, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I have a downloader class which get an InputStream and OutputStream and works like this:

```
while (isCanceled() == false) {
     synchronized (inputStream) {
         readCount = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
     }
     if (readCount < 0) {
         break;
     }
     pipedOutputStream.write(readBuffer, 0, readCount);
}
```

It works fine on all android versions, but after I updated my android to 7 (Nougat) it takes almost 4 seconds to write to outputStream(in other android versions it takes a few milliseconds).
My outputStream field is of type PipedOutputStream.

Here is my variables initializition:

```
URLConnection connection = getConnection();
inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInputStream);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: where / how are you using `pipedInputStream` and `pipedOutputStream` ?

Comment: This line of my code: outputStream.write(readBuffer, 0, readCount); takes almost 4 seconds to run and I'v already wrote the initilization

Comment: post the code of both `Thread`s where you are writing / reading the piped streams

Comment: The above while loop is inside the AsyncTask.

Comment: in the above while loop you are NOT using any piped stream, will you post the complete code of both `Thread`s?

Comment: Sorry! I updated the code, in while loop: pipedOutputStream.write(readBuffer, 0, readCount);

Comment: and where are you reading `pipedInputStream`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130404/discussion-between-hojjat-and-pskink).